# Cannot open Bashrc in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: bash, bashrc

I'm unable to open bashrc file in ubuntu. I tried using `gedit ~/.bashrc` and vi commands but its not opening.

When I open a terminal everytime, its displaying the problem like

```
bash: export: `/opt/grads-2.1.0.oga.1/Contents/Resources/SampleDatasets :/usr/local/ferret/bin:/home/user/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin': not a valid identifier
```

After running the `.profile`, I'm getting the issues like

```
user@revathi:~$ . ~/.profile
bash: lesspipe: No such file or directory
bash: dircolors: No such file or directory
bash: ls: No such file or directory
bash: grep: No such file or directory
bash: export: `/opt/grads-2.1.0.oga.1/Contents/Resources/SampleDatasets :/usr/local/ferret/bin:': not a valid identifier
```

Could anyone please help me to fix the path?

Comment: What error do you get using gedit or vi?

Comment: user@revathi:~$ gedit ~./bashrc     
bash: gedit: No such file or directory        is displayed

Comment: user@revathi:~$ gedit ~/.bashrc
                                                                                                                         
Command 'gedit' is available in '/usr/bin/gedit'
                                                                                                                                      
 The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
                              gedit: command not found

Answer (score 2):

You changed your PATH variable and included a space which hinders the system to find crucial programs. Call `gedit` with the full path with

```
/usr/bin/gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and correct the error. I suspect the faulty line looks like this in your case:

```
PATH="/opt/grads-2.1.0.oga.1/Contents/Resources/SampleDatasets :$PATH"
```

while it should be

```
PATH="/opt/grads-2.1.0.oga.1/Contents/Resources/SampleDatasets:$PATH"
```

instead. Then save the file, source it with `. ~/.bashrc` or just open a new terminal and your terminal should be back to normal.